# does page lock locks more than one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have two tables withmin size 4kb each and present in one page.
If I had apply intent lock for a key in table1 for update operation then the hierrachy will be

key-> page->extent locks will be applied.

then can I able to retrive data from second table which is not involved in update operation

Comment: afair different tables cannot occupy the same page

Comment: eventhought the size is adjusted.... then the memory will be waste

Answer (score 3):

The hierarchy is object->page-row. Extents are not involved in locking. The hierarchy is always from container to contained.

Different objects (tables) cannot overlap. Pages are not shared, and since extents are not involved in locking, mixed extents do not matter.

Comment: even does the data present in more pages?

Comment: if table is 3 kb then remaining 5kb can be allocated to another table. in that aspect if we apply page lock does tat effects another table

Comment: As I sayed, **pages are not shared**. Read [Understanding Pages and Extents](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Table and Index Organization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: thanq @remus rusanu... I read.. does the remaining space in the page is wasted?